# undefined method `paginate' despite having will_paginate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a rails newbie and I'm trying to construct a feed of posts that are pulled from the database based on the characteristic of a category (in this case music). The action getting flagged is:

```
def music
    @music_wads = Wad.find_by(category: "Music").paginate(page: params[:page])      
end
```

Perhaps I'm making an error with the syntax, but I have the gem will_paginate installed. I have yet to actually add the <%= will_paginate @music_wads %> to my view however. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you restart your application after adding the gem dependency?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm effectively using the source code from the Hartl tutorial, but trying to make posts that paginate on a feed depending on an attribute I added to the table called "category".

Comment: When you add something to your `Gemfile` you need to restart your development server process. It depends on how you launched it, as `rails s` is different from [Puma-dev](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev) and others. You won't see the `paginate` method until that gem is loaded in on server boot. Anything in `/app` or `/config/routes.rb` is automatically reloaded, but fundamental changes like this require a hard restart of the process.

Comment: how do I do this hard restart? i used the command rails s to run the server, and simply ended and restart the server using the same commands to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure `gem 'paginate'` is listed and `bundle check` checks out?

Comment: Do you mean gem 'will_paginate' ?

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: yes it is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.where` instead of `.find_by`:

```
@music_wads = Wad.where(category: "Music").paginate(page: params[:page])
```

`.find_by` returns first record matching your conditions, while `.paginate` needs an `ActiveRecord::Relation` collection of records to work.

Comment: The change resolves the issue in my controller but causes an error in my view. I'm trying to execute <%= @music_wads.long_form %>  where long_form is column on my wads table with data type text. I assumed rails knew how to evaluate this expression since it went through before I tried to paginate these posts.

Comment: @music_wads is now a collection of records, to access data in records you have to iterate it first. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#listing-all-articles I recommend going through whole guide, if you are a newbie it really is the first tutorial you should learn from.

Comment: To reiterate, I am a newbie at this. Can you please explain what that means as I am trying to learn? Thank you.

Comment: Ahhh nevermind I understand now. Have to call on EACH instance individually

Comment: <% @music_wads.each do |music_wad| %>
  <%= music_wad.long_form %>
<% end %>
Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I changed it to that after you edited your message, thank you though